# LEFT JOIN doesn't play nicely with partitioned tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a query in Postgres that joins 2 tables, one of them is partitioned. The execution plan was showing the query would hit all of the partitions of the table, even though I'm including the partitioning key in the query.

I finally realized the issue was a `LEFT JOIN` I had. If I replace `A LEFT JOIN B` by `A, B` then Postgres starts targeting only 1 partition instead of all of the partitions.

Anybody knows if it's a bug in Postgres execution planner?

Here the *simplified* query:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT in_memory_table.my_col
    FROM (SELECT '2019-08-09 19:00:00+00:00') in_memory_table(my_col)
    LEFT JOIN partitioned_table
    ON (partitioned_table.id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'
        AND partitioned_table.my_col = in_memory_table.my_col);
```

This yields this execution plan:

```
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..58.28 rows=1 width=8)
   Join Filter: (partitioned_table_201908_partition.my_col = ('2019-08-09 19:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.56..58.17 rows=7 width=8)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_201908_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_201908_partition  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_201909_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_201909_partition  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_201910_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_201910_partition  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_201911_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_201911_partition  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_201912_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_201912_partition  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_202001_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_202001_partition  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_pkey on partitioned_table_000000_partition  (cost=0.70..8.72 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
(18 rows)
```

If I instead do this:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT in_memory_table.my_col
    FROM (SELECT '2019-08-09 19:00:00+00:00') in_memory_table(my_col),
    partitioned_table
    WHERE (partitioned_table.id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'
        AND partitioned_table.my_col = in_memory_table.my_col);
```

Then the execution plan looks how I expected it to look:

```
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=0.56..8.59 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Index Scan using partitioned_table_201908_partition_pkey on partitioned_table_201908_partition  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=8)
         Index Cond: (id = '1111111111111111122222222222222'::uuid)
         Filter: (result_timestamp = '2019-08-09 19:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
```

Why is the `LEFT JOIN` version hitting all partitions?

## Other info

- I'm using Postgres 11.1
- `my_col` is the partitioning key (partitioned by range)
- Why am I using `LEFT JOIN`? this is a simplified version, the real one uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but that one is harder to ask about (I cannot transform the `ON` into a `WHERE` in that one).

Comment: `A LEFT JOIN B` is an outer join (it's the same as `left outer join`)  but `A, B where ... ` is an inner join, obviously they result in different plans. The number of rows from `a` is not restricted in an outer join, so the planner apparently assumes that it needs all partitions

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking a LEFT JOIN was an inner join.